# Is there a moving knife procedure for envy-free cake cutting with connected pieces?

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, fair-division

In the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envy-free_cake-cutting) on envy-free cake cutting, continuous "moving knife" algorithms for envy free cake cutting to connected pieces is only mentioned for up to 4 players. As the wikipedia article does not say so explicitly, is there a general solution?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is an open question. Some information can be found in:

Branzei and Nisan (2017), [The Query Complexity of Cake Cutting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02946).